# When should I use reg instead of wire?

Tags: logic, verilog, circuit

I'm confused about reg and wire when I was doing my homework. I could not understand differences between reg and wire exactly. Can you explain shortly? Also, I wonder that what will happen when I use `output q` instead of `output reg q`?

Comment: @Qui I can't believe that this question hadn't been asked before, but could not find such a thing. I found the question you referred to and don't think it a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965504/difference-between-wire-and-reg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module

Comment: This has to be the most asked question about Verilog since it was invented. My answer: http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg

Comment: @dave_59 Which is why I was surprised I couldn't find a similar question. This is indeed a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module; the one cited at the top is not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360508/using-wire-or-reg-with-input-or-output-in-verilog

Comment: The link from dave_59 is now status 500 but can be found at archive.org: ["What’s the deal with those wire’s and reg’s in Verilog"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210414095803/https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/).

Answer (score 4):

In *simulation*, a Verilog `wire` behaves like a piece of metal, a track, a wire, whilst a Verilog `reg` is a variable, it is storage*.

The difference between them in simulation can be illustrated by showing what happens if I assign to them from more than one place. If I assign to a `wire` from more than one place, the simulation will behave exactly as if I had shorted those two wires together. So,

```
wire w;
assign w = 1'b1;
assign w = 1'b0;
initial
   $display("w= %b", w);
```

will display `x`. The value of `w` will be `x` because one `assign` is driving `1'b1` and the other `1'b0` and so this will *resolve* to an `x`. In this way it is modelling the behavoiur of real hardware, where `x` represents an *unknown* value (the value of a real piece of wire drive high by one driver and low by another will really be unknown).

If I assign to a `reg` - a variable - from more than one place, I will get different behaviour. Instead of *resolving* to an `x`, the `reg` will just take whatever value is assigned last. So,

```
reg r;

initial
  r = 1'b1;

initial
  r = 1'b0;

initial
   #1 $display("r= %b", r);
```

will display either `1` or `0` depending on which initial block is executed last (something that is not deterministic).

Notice, that the `reg` is driven from `initial` blocks. A `reg` has to be driven from an `initial` or an `always` block (so-called *procedural code*). Assuming you are writing Verilog, not System Verilog, you cannot assign to a `reg` from an `assign` statement nor from the output of an instantiated module. So, **if you want to assign to something from procedural code, you have to use a `reg`; if you want to assign to something from an `assign` statement or the output of an instantiated module, it has to be a `wire`.** And, therefore it follows that whether you define an `output` as a `reg` or a `wire` depends entirely on where you're assigning to it. If you're assigning to it from an `always` block, it needs to be a `reg`; if you're assigning to it from an `assign` statement or the output of an instantiated module, it needs to be a `wire`.

That is the difference in the behaviour of a `reg` and a `wire` in simulation. Your synthesiser, will interpret a `reg` differently. If you assign to a `reg` from more than one `always` block (you can't synthesise `initial` blocks), then you logic synthesiser will synthesise two pieces of hardware driving the same piece of metal, track, wire, whatever - something you probably don't want.

*That *does not* mean a `reg` will necessarily become storage (ie a flip-flop) when synthesised. Whether, a `reg becomes a flip-flop or combinational logic depends on whether it is assigned in a sequential- or combinational-style always block.

Comment: Note that `reg` does not hold storage if the `always` block implements combinatorial logic, thus always assign to the the `reg`.  In that case the `reg` is like a `wire` from a continuous assign implementing the same function.  Btw. if possible, consider using SystemVerilog `logic` type instead, since this merges `wire` and `reg` so you don't have to update the declaration depending on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

output q is equivalent to output wire q.

reg is used for sequential logic such as flop. It is also required in always* blocks even for the combo blocks.
wire is used for the combinatorial logic.